# Rails 3 Unable to access log file on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, production-environment

I am deploying my web application to my server and everything works perfectly except I cannot find a way to get rid of the following error message below. Before deploying I have a development, and production.rb file in my log but when pushing to the server there is nothing there and I cannot create it. I have looked for other solutions but so far nothing has worked, How can I solve this error?

```
Rails Error: Unable to access log file. Please ensure that
/var/www/websites/public/appname/releases/20120608236602/log/production.log
exists and is chmod 0666. The log level has been raised to WARN and
the output directed to STDERR until the problem is fixed.
```

Comment: How are you deploying your app?

Comment: @cheeseweasel I am deploying with capistrano

Comment: I believe by default, Capistrano should set up your log folder in the appname/shared folder, and releases/xxx/log should be a symlink, is this the case?

Comment: I think the real cause is http://bradhe.wordpress.com/2011/06/26/a-sneaky-rails-3-bug-in-logging/  check your `config.log_level` is set to correct symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As that error message states, the logging process cannot access the log file. This would be due to the permissions on  `/var/www/websites/public/appname/releases/20120608236602/log`.

You can change the permissions on that dir with:

```
chmod -R 0666 /var/www/websites/public/appname/releases/20120608236602/log
```

Comment: I use sudo cmd above and it works but when trying to update rails app it does not. Anyway to have this done by default so I do not have to change permission manually everytime?

Comment: I would follow @cheeseweasel's advice to use symlinks in a production release.