# Production.log file becomes read-only after every ElasticBeanstalk deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

My problem is similar to [Rails 3 Unable to access log file on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10957645/rails-3-unable-to-access-log-file-on-server) except that it re-occurs every time I use `eb deploy` to upload a new version of my code.

The steps I'm taking are

- `eb deploy`
- `eb ssh`
- `ls -la /var/app/current/log/` which returns `-rw-r--r--`
- `sudo chmod 0664 /var/app/current/log/production.log`

The production.log file is now writeable. But if I make further changes to my code and re-deploy, the problem has reoccured:

- `eb deploy`
- `eb ssh`
- `ls -la /var/app/current/log/` which returns `-rw-r--r--`

The production.log file is not included in the uploaded bundle. How can I prevent this file from being made read-only after every deployment?

Using Rails 4.2.0 on ElasticBeanstalk

Comment: is the production log owned by a different user than the server process is running as?  That seems odd? what user does server run as ,who owns the process? are you deploying as root?

Comment: @doon I'm a Rails noob so I'm not sure of those. `whoami` returns `ec2-user` and `ls -la` shows `webapp`, who I presume is the owner of the file(?) Do either of those help?

Comment: which stack are you running?  Puma / Passenger?

Comment: You could add a container command that chmod your file to the permissions you want.

Comment: @doon I'm on 64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v2.0.0 running Ruby 2.0 (Passenger Standalone)

Comment: @Gustaf good idea, but I can't get it to work. Do you know the correct syntax? I tried `command: "sudo chmod 0664 /var/app/current/log/production.log"` but this returns "sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo"

Comment: You can't run sudo like that (different topic), but you don't need it anyway. The script is run by root anyway so just remove it =)